# IntelliJ Idea: cannot connect to repository (SVN)

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, plink

I have been able to connect with current version of Idea, but I had to roll back (license) to 2017.1. Since then I have not been able to connect to repository via SVN (on Windows 7).

What worked for me with 2018.3:
 - enabled interactive mode
 - SSH executable set to TortoisePlink
 - user name set
 - private key loaded

I have copied settings to 2017.1, but it results in error:
"SVN E170013: Unable to connect to a repository... E170012: Can't create tunnelsvn: E720087: Can't create tunnel:The parameter is incorrect"

I have set the SVN_SSH system variable, I am using double slashes in the path ("\"), I have the key loaded in Pageant, I can get to the repository through Putty.

When I turn off "Use command line client" option, I can browse the repository in the SVN Repositories tool window, but I cannot open files / change branches for update operation (authentication window asks me for username and password, but I am using a key to log in...).

I think I have tried every possible combination, but with little success. Is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the path to executable is incorrect - in older versions, it had to use double slashes.

Comment: Yes, marking the path to "SSH executable" with \\ instead of \ (C:\\Program Files\\..) solved the problem. Thanks a lot!